# Converting String[] args. to int/double in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a main programs "String[] args" into 5 ints, and 4 doubles. (i know it's kind of confusing)

The way i was thinking of doing it was having a forreach loop to loop through String args[] and add them to an int array (for the first 5), however i had to use  for the array, so it doesn't work.

```
if (args != null) {
        // If arguments where given, use the arguments and run the program
        // NEED TO SOMEHOW CONVERT ARGS INTO INTEGER FORM AFTER BEING PASSED IN
        ArrayList<Integer> valArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(10); // could be 9
        for (String val : args) {
            // Parse the string and add it to valArray
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(val);
            valArr.add(temp);
        }   

        CarPark cp = new CarPark(valArr[0], valArr[1], valArr[2], valArr[3]);
```

this is what i'm looking at at the moment... am i completely wrong? or close?

Comment: Why can't you use `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`?

Comment: You are going to convert last 4 doubles into int, and will get `NumberFormatException` in this way

Comment: I can, and should. but how do i go from that to sending them into the constructor?

Comment: How confident are you that they will be ints and doubles? You might want to throw a try/catch block in there to set it to 0 if a format exception is caught if it's not. Otherwise I agree with @LuiggiMendoza .. good to use two for statements after you check to make sure the required number of args are there.

Comment: They are 100% 5 ints, 4 doubles. if the user does not enter enough values, then the program should use the defaults (which already works/runs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse it with two indexing `for` loops.

```
int[] myInts = new int[5];
double[] myDoubles = new double[4];

// Initialize these arrays with "defaults" here.

// Notice how we handle the possibility of the user not entering enough values.
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(5, args.length); i++)
    myInts[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(4, args.length - 5); i++)
    myDoubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(args[i+5]);

CarPark cp = new CarPark(myInts[0], myInts[1], myInts[2], myInts[3]);
```

Comment: Would "mydoubles" start at [0] for the first double, or start at 5 or 6?

Comment: @user2926862, The left side starts at `[0]`, but it starts reading from `args[5]`.

Comment: @user2926862, See the update to handle the case where the user does not input enough values.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the values from the array list as given below

```
CarPark cp = new CarPark(valArr.get(0), valArr.get(1), valArr.get(2), valArr.get(3));
```

Comment: are you getting any NumberFormatException anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

look at [ArrayList Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

above could be like this

```
CarPark cp = new CarPark(valArr.get(0), valArr.get(1), valArr.get(2), valArr.get(3));
```

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood i dont know when he posted. while i'm typing that guy posted. i'm not responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
if (args != null) {
        // If arguments where given, use the arguments and run the program
        // NEED TO SOMEHOW CONVERT ARGS INTO INTEGER FORM AFTER BEING PASSED IN
        ArrayList<Integer> valArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(10); // could be 9
        for (String val : args) {
            // Parse the string and add it to valArray
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(val);
            valArr.add(temp);
        }
CarPark cp = new CarPark(valArr.get(0), valArr.get(1), valArr.get(2), valArr.get(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your corrected code:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String args[]){


            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        args=new String[4];
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter value no- "+(i+1));
            args[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
             ArrayList<Integer> valArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
            if (args != null) {
            // If arguments where given, use the arguments and run the program
            // NEED TO SOMEHOW CONVERT ARGS INTO INTEGER FORM AFTER BEING PASSED IN
            // could be 9
            for (String val : args) {
                // Parse the string and add it to valArray
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(val.trim());
                valArr.add(temp);
            }
        }
            System.out.println(valArr);
            //CarPark cp = new CarPark(valArr[0], valArr[1], valArr[2], valArr[3]); 
        }
        }
```

This is just the code for Integer part in similar way you can extend the args array length and include double values, Remeber to use val.trim() to remove whitespaces otherwise it will throw NumberFormatException.